# how to write Makefile for existing project for visual studio 2008 in windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

i had two c++ files and two header files and one main file. i am trying to write Makefile to compile. i am unable to do that in visual studio 2008 on windows. so please help me if you want code also i can show you.

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to setup the build parameters, linkers, libraries, etc you should do it through the project configuration property in Visual Studio environment. Right click on your project and select property for it.